# How to use another layout id?

Tags: android

In my application I have used one alert box.. In this alert box, I give another layout to be show.. using `setView()` method.. I have a problem. How to use layout elements id in my activity?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volume, null);
                builder.setTitle("Volume");
                builder.setView(layout);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                alert1.show();
```

Comment: Hai, In my application use a volume control seekbar. that should be appear on one buuton click. so i am use alert box.that alert box have one volume layout..my problam is i didn't use seekbar id..

Comment: then i guess you should assign an ID to your seekbar in xml layout in order to reference to it later in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows you how to show a custom alert and get a view from that custom layout:

```
    AlertDialog mDialog = null;

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    final AlertDialog.Builder my_Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    ImageView imageViewInsideLayout = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageviewLayout);

    my_Dialog.setView(layout);
    mDialog = my_Dialog.create();
    mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

In your activity:

```
....
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volume, null);
.....
View some = layout.findViewById(YOUR_VIEW_ID);
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to refer to view inside your custom layout, then do the following:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.your_editText);
Button editText = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
.
.
.
//and so one with other views
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get reference to view by `builder.findViewById( R.id.restart );`